# SCH,singular cardinal hypothesis, GCH, relationship

Tags: cardinals

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_cardinals_hypothesis) it is stated that SCH is a consequence of GCH and also SCH is whether GCH might *fail* at a singular cardinal. These two condition seem yield a contradiction:does SCH follow from failing or holding GCH at singular cardinals?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathsf{GCH}$ says that $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$ for all infinite cardinals $\kappa$. $\mathsf{SCH}$ says that $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$ for all singular strong limit cardinals $\kappa$. Clearly the first statement implies the second.

The question was, whether, if $\mathsf{GCH}$ is false, the smallest infinite cardinal $\kappa$ for which $2^\kappa>\kappa^+$ can be singular. Failure of $\mathsf{SCH}$ says that it can be, and $\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg\mathsf{SCH}$ is known to be equiconsistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ plus the existence of a sufficiently large measureable cardinal.

Comment: Yes, thank you,Can you please also have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035765/bolean-algebras-filter-on-index-set-finite-sets-as-indeces-to-elements-of-bool) question about filters and boolean algebras in a paper by Shelah?